# How to efficient sort arrays by date with Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a .csv input file that i am reading using Python 3.6.3, that has the following abbreviated outline

```
Day,Month,Year,Debit(U.S. Dollars)
1,March,2016,487.00
1,March,2016,27.48
6,Februaray,2016,47.81
9,June,2017,218.55
```

I am reading in the data using the .csv module such that the first column is read to the variable `Day`, the second column is read to the variable `Month`, the third column is read to the variable `Year`, and the fourth column is read to the variable `Debit`.  Each variable is transformed into a numpy array.  When I print the variables I get the following output.

```
>>> print(Day)
>>> [1 6 9]
>>> print(Month)
>>> [March March February]
>>> print(Year)
>>> [2016 2016 2016, 2017]
>>> print(Debit)
>>> [487.00 27.48 47.81 218.55]
```

I would like to find a way to efficiently sort the arrays by date, which is predicated on the combination of the `Day`, `Month`, and `Year` arrays, such that when printed I get the following results

```
>>> print(Day)
>>> [6 1 1 9]
>>> print(Month)
>>> [February March March June]
>>> print(Year)
>>> [2016 2016 2016 2017]
>>> print(47.81 487.00 27.48 218.55]
```

I have considered just having a calendar algorithm walk through every date between the first and last date and passing the data points to a new array, if an expense occurs on that date, but that does not seem like a very efficient method.  Does anyone have any idea on a good/efficient way to sort the arrays by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to prepend a `datetime` representation of the combined date elements to the start of each row. This would then make all of the elements correctly sortable. The list of rows can then be converted into a list of columns using `*zip()`:

```
from datetime import datetime    
import csv

data = []

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv_reader:
        data.append([datetime.strptime('{} {} {}'.format(*row[:3]), '%d %B %Y')] + row)

sorted_cols = list(zip(*sorted(data)))

print("Days", sorted_cols[1])
print("Months", sorted_cols[2])
print("Years", sorted_cols[3])
print("Debits", sorted_cols[4])
```

This would give you:

```
Days ('6', '1', '1', '9')
Months ('February', 'March', 'March', 'June')
Years ('2016', '2016', '2016', '2017')
Debits ('47.81', '27.48', '487.00', '218.55')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since each row (not column) is one data entry, I might consider reading by row and not column. But if you don't have control over that, you can convert everything to datetime objects, sort by that and then overwrite your existing arrays:

```
from datetime import datetime

entries = []
for i, day in enumerate(days):
  debit = Debut[i]
  time = datetime(Year[1], Month[1], day)
  entries.append([time, debit])
entries.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

# At this point you can either just use the entries array for your purposes
# or re-create your newly-sorted arrays using list comprehensions
Day = [entry[0].day for entry in entries]
Month = [entry[0].month for entry in entries]
Year = [entry[0].year for entry in entries]
Debit = [entry[1] for entry in entries]
```

Comment: This was a huge help, thank you for the information.

Comment: No problem, and glad it helped! If your issue is solved, mind marking the question as answered?

Comment: Your comment was useful in helping get a better understanding of how to attack the problem.  However, the solution recommended Martin Evans was more precisely the answer I was looking for, so I marked his solution as answered.  I tried to mark yours, but then it unchecked is answered box.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that his had been marked. No worries, glad to help!